# Connecting from local VM to AWS instancec

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services

This may be fairly simple for many of the experts here, however, i am struggling on this one.

I have a AWS instance running windows 2012 server and virtual box running windows 7 on ubuntu host.

I am trying to point my windows 7 machine to the AWS IP ( Need the AWS IP to be the DNS for the windows 7 machine )

My AWS IP has a 172.31.23.X range and i am not sure how to setup my windows 7 machine to be able to talk to it.

I have set the host only card in virtualbox with 172.31.x.x settings and the windows machine is not able to ping the AWS instance.

I am not sure what i am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

172.31.0.0/16 is a [private IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) address inside AWS, you can't access it from the public internet (more info [here](http://whatismyipaddress.com/private-ip)). You need to assign an elastic IP address so it has a public IP. You do this in the EC2 area of AWS, and they're free.

Alternately you could set up a virtual private network (VPN) but that's more complex.